# Character pointer and Character difference in C

Tags: c, gcc

The following code doesnt code doesn't give any error

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char c='c';
    //*c='a';
    printf("\n%c\n",c);
}
```

But the following code gives a warning and gives no output

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char *c='c';
    //*c='a';
    printf("\n%c\n",*c);
}

test.c:4:10: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: `c` is a pointer.  `'c'` is a `char`.  `char *c='c';` --> bad karma.  Use `char *c= "c"; printf("\n%s\n",c);` instead.

Comment: well, because a `char` is not the same things as a `char *`?

Comment: `char *c` should point to a valid memory address if you want to use `*c` (which yields a memory access operation). The value of `'c'` (typically 99) is most likely not a valid memory address in your program.

Comment: @user567879: I think that's chux's way of saying "undefined behavior".

Comment: @chux Beginner doubt. Why changing to `char *c="c"` works with `%s`

Comment: You need to get a decent C primer and start reading. This question and hundreds more will be answered for you in the first couple of chapters.

Comment: @chux `'c'` is `int` in `C`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, I sitand corrected: `'c'` is an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to understand what is happening, it is necessary to understand the difference between `'c'` and `"c"` literals (constants):

- Character literal `'c'` is a numeric constant, a shorthand to writing `(char)99` (assuming ASCII encoding)
- String literal `"c"` represents an address of a two-character sequence `{'c', '\0'}`

Had you used `"c"` instead of `'c'`, your second code snippet would have worked. You need to assign an address to `char*`, and `"c"` gives you an address. However, `'c'` is *not* an address, it's a numeric constant. That's why you get a warning.

When you dereference a constant `'c'` re-interpreted as a pointer, you get undefined behavior. That is why `printf` does not print anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *c='c';
//*c='a';
printf("\n%c\n",*c);
```

You're trying to declare a pointer c by `char *c;`

Pointer is a variable which holds the memory location of another variable,so

```
char *c='c';
```

doesn't makes any sense
a pointer can hold hold the address of a memory locat

Answer (score 0):

Types matter.

In the first snippet, the type of the variable `c` is `char`, which is an integral type.  The *expression* `'c'` has type `int`, and its value is whatever code is used for the character 'c' (in ASCII, it would be 99).  The types `int` and `char` are *compatible*; you can assign one to the other without needing a cast, assuming the value is representable in the target type.  In this case, the value of `'c'` is representable in an object of type `char`.

In the second snippet, the type of `c` is `char *`, which is a *pointer* type.  Pointer types and integral types are not compatible, and you can't assign one to the other without a cast, which is why you got the diagnostic.  The *wrong* way to fix it would be

```
char *c = (char *) 'c';
```

which takes the value of the expression `'c'` (99), converts it to a pointer type, and assigns the resulting pointer value to `c`.  This is the *wrong* way to fix it because the
resulting pointer value is most likely not a valid address.

What you probably meant to do was something along the lines of

```
char *c = "c"; // note double quotes
```

The expressiuon `"c"` is a *string literal*; it is a 2-element array of `char` containing the values `{'c', 0 }`.  Under most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.  So in the declaration above, the *address* of the first character of the string literal `"c"` is assigned to the pointer variable `c`.